# Why can't I drag and drop widgets into a toolbar in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I have an Android activity with a `Toolbar` inside an `AppBarLayout` and I would like to add widgets to it. When I try to drag and drop a widget onto the `Toolbar` in the Designer, it doesn't work and the cursor shows a symbol indicating that it can't be added.

There are many questions on StackOverflow all asking the same thing but the answers all seem to be about the distinction between `activity_*.xml` and `content_*.xml`. This is not the issue for me, I'm using the `activity_*.xml` file which definitely includes the `Toolbar`. I can also add widgets manually in the XML file and they appear in the designer; it's only the drag and drop that isn't working.

Any ideas why this doesn't work or how to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I still don't have enough reps to comment because this is a new account. But have you tried writing on the xml instead? Right below the palette toolbox, you can switch from design to text and vice versa. And the xml code can easily be googled.

Comment: Yes, writing the XML works fine. I'm trying to figure out why the drag and drop interface isn't allowing me to place widgets.

Comment: You're probably not hitting where it should go. That is why I always opt to use xml because i find the designer faulty. Then I just open preview on the xml so I can see what's actually happening, real time.